# Apply operations to all dataframes in a dictionary without loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, dataframe

I have done following

```
myrng=range(1971,2009)
d = {}
for name in myrng:
    wd1=pd.read_csv('D:\\temp\\'+str(name)+'.csv')
    d[str(name)] = wd1
    del wd1
d.keys()
```

gives

```
dict_keys(['1971',.... '2009'])
```

Each of the 1971...2009 has columns: 'state' 'districts' and 'dates'

I want to create a column `cat` in all data frames in "d" which will have concatenated values of `state` and `districts` columns.

I have another dataframe say df which also has one column `cat`.

I want to merge this to all dataframes in d. The point is I want to avoid loops.
I can do it with for loop, as I want to do it multiple times.

The for code can be like following

```
for name in myrng:
    A=d[str(name)]
    A['cat']=A.state + A.district
    A= pd.merge(df,A ....### option###)
```

do remaining calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### With `dict` of dataframes, you can't avoid a loop

If you want to keep your data structured as a dictionary of dataframes, you can't avoid a `for` loop. This is because each dataframe value within your dictionary is a separate `pd.DataFrame` instance. You can't temporarily link them for one or more operations.

#### Simplifying logic

You can use a list comprehension with [`pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to simply your logic / loop:

```
def transformer(df):
    df['cat'] = df['state'] + df['district']
    df = pd.merge(df, ...)
    return df

d = {name: pd.read_csv(fr'D:\temp\{name}.csv').pipe(transformer) for name in myrng}
```

#### Combining dataframes in your `dict`

If you want to avoid loops, you can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to combine dataframes in your dictionary and apply your transformations:

```
df_combined = pd.concat(d.values()).pipe(transformer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply "With dict of dataframes, you can't avoid a loop" I can't just concat them as row sequence in each year might be different different

Comment: @makarandkulkarni, Sure, so you can't do what you want. I hope I've explained *why* this is the case.

Comment: Not possible will also save my time required for surfing on net, Instead I shall ask my pc to work for more time

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a generator into `pd.concat` to concatenate all the file data together. Then with the result, you can calculate the `'cat'` column.

```
myrng=range(1971,2009)
data = pd.concat(
    pd.read_csv('D:\\temp\\'+str(name)+'.csv', usecols=['dates', 'state', 'district'])
    for name in myrng
)
data['cat'] = data['state'] + data['district']
```

Comment: nope  I can't just concat them as row sequence in each year might be different

Comment: @makarandkulkarni You can pass a `usecols` argument to specify a column order as described here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html, would that fix the problem?